# Libreoffice 7.5.6 provided in Ubuntu 23.04 doesnt open CMIS

Tags: updates, libreoffice, 23.04

Libreoffice included in Ubuntu 23.04 version is unable to open CMIS Alfresco 4/5, no repository is recognized, even the previously set old one.

I was upgrading from 22.04 LTS and this feature got lost. Previously (22.04 LTS) it was working fine.

I downloaded and installed deb packages from Libreoffice site and everything works fine, even the old repository settings.

EDIT 09/30/2023

One of the main functionalities of Libreoffice is the ability to online edit docs from Alfresco CMIS Repository. If I download and install LibreOffice 7.5.6 (stable) DEB packages from LibreOffice.org, everything works fine.

If I install (i.e. using Synaptic) LibreOffice DEB packages from Ubuntu 23.04 official repositories, the functionality fails in setting process. I refer to the same LibreOffice versions (from LibreOffice.org and from Ubuntu 23.04 official respositories).

Previously, in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, using LibreOffice 7.3 installed from Ubuntu official repos everything worked fine, so I write here problema appears in Ubuntu 23.04 repostitories packages.

Thanks.

Any help?

Comment: Reinstall 22.04. This sounds like a LibreOffice bug. Bugs are off topic here.

Comment: `I downloaded and installed deb packages from Libreoffice site and everything works fine, even the old repository settings.` -- Then just use it

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to make it a bit clearer? What's your intention? Do you just want to mention the issue? If so, you should [report a bug at LibreOffice](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/QA/BugReport). If you are looking for a solution, be more specific about your issue, because you seem to have already found a solution (install the deb package), so it's not clear what your actual question is.

Comment: So you are reporting a bug, judging by your last edit. However this is not the correct place to do that. Please see the link in [my previous comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1486845/libreoffice-7-5-6-provided-in-ubuntu-23-04-doesnt-open-cmis#comment2604569_1486845) with instructions about how and where to report a LibreOffice bug. Thanks!